# compiled matlab filename as parameter

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, compiled

I compiled some Matlab code on Centos 5.

I try to run it like this:

```
run_cnaseq006.sh /projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714/ "/home/rcorbett/slx_service_rc/etc/cnv_test_data/CNV_test/config.m"
------------------------------------------
Setting up environment variables
---
LD_LIBRARY_PATH is .:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//runtime/glnxa64:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//bin/glnxa64:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//sys/os/glnxa64:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/client:/projects/rcorbettprj2/mutationSeq/MCR/v714//sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64
??? Error using ==> run at 65
/home/rcorbett/slx_service_rc/etc/cnv_test_data/CNV_test/config.m not found.
```

However, I can easily see that the file does exist:

```
ll /home/rcorbett/slx_service_rc/etc/cnv_test_data/CNV_test/config.m
-rw-r--r-- 1 rcorbett users 3 Aug 13 09:10 /home/rcorbett/slx_service_rc/etc/cnv_test_data/CNV_test/config.m
```

I tried different quotes, and no quotes, but I can't figure out why it won't execute the file.  The Code works fine as uncompiled matlab code,   so something funny is happening after compilation that affects the ability to identify the file.

*EDIT:* run_cnaseq006.sh is the auto generated shell script for running my compiled code.  It is about 40 lines, so doesn't copy well into here.   However, I can say it is just a wrapper to make sure all the libraries are loaded when I run my compiled code.   All the compiled code I have get pretty much the exact shell script wrapper.

Comment: This might help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/291369

Comment: Could you post the contents of `run_cnaseq006.sh`?

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to this link:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/

The "run" command uses path management functions like "cd".  According to the above article such activities are unsupported in compiled applications, and can create unpredictable results.

I resigned to using an alternate approach to define my runtime variables by reading the file with getline and using "eval" to load my variables into memory.